# How to put two blocks inline in menu bar

Tags: routes, blocks, theming

In every theme I tested so far, when a block is added to Menu bar area, each block is always shown stacked in pile, my question is:

> There is a way to to make **two or more blocks** showing **inline** in **menu bar** area?

Please don't say that the question is "too generic", since I tested a plenty of template and they all stack blocks in pile!

Tpl modifications &/or css solutions are both welcome.
No scripting please.

Comment: are the blocks your are placing in the menu area for menus ?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question on how to align blocks horizontally in a region, which calls for a CSS solution.

There are a few things to consider before you start:

- Blocks have no defined width. Normally the outer wrapper is just a
  div, as determined by the block.tpl file, and it is precisely because of
  this that they take up all the horizontal space given to them. That
  is why they stack vertically.
- Each theme might be slightly different in handling floats. Some
  themes are fixed width, some are fluid, some have a built in
  framework for handling layout, most don't.

For a theme that has a fluid layout without a built-in layout framework, and showing two blocks inline, you can do this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:761px) {
    .region-featured:before,
    .region-featured:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        display: table; /* 2 */
    }

    .region-featured:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    /**
     * For IE 6/7 only
     * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
     */
    .region-featured {
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    .region-featured .block {
        width:50%;
        float:left;
    }
}
```

This will float two blocks side by side when the overall width is greater than 760px. If you have a fixed width site, then remove the media query. Also note the clearfix styling (when using a layout manager it will just be a class) which ensures that the region wrapper grows vertically to enclose the blocks.

The width of the block was set to 50% because there are two blocks that I wanted to float next to each other (100% / 2 = 50%). For three blocks you will set a width of 33.333333% etc.

When using a layout framework (recommended, and mostly baked into the theme), then it will all just be a matter of assigning proper classes, so you would then need to assign a region-class in the page template to the region, and assign classes to the blocks, perhaps using a module like [Block Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class), or also inside the block or region template file.

For a theme with a baked-in layout framework, look at [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap), amongst numerous others. It is extremely easy to use, but you must familiarise yourself with the official bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com). Bootstrap is not Drupal specific. It is just a framework that the Drupal Bootstrap theme developers adopted.

For more CSS solutions on aligning Divs horizontally, [How to Align Divs Horizontally in CSS](http://www.ehow.com/how_8449962_align-divs-horizontally-css.html)